# File Encryption/Decryption in c#

Tags: c#, encryption

I need to encrypt/decrypt a file in c# using NCrypto or BouncyCastle libraries. I also need to use AES and RSA algorithm and create a key. Are there any good guides or tutorials for complete beginners? I googled some and didn't find any basic guide. Thank you.

Comment: I find it hard to believe Google did let you down

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place to ask for tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginners shouldn't be doing this.

Before jumping into cryptography maybe get an understanding of what it is, how it works and at last learn the programming language.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography

Anyways here is an example for BountyCastle:
http://elian.co.uk/post/2009/07/29/Bouncy-Castle-CSharp.aspx